# How to convert a string to a Date without moment.js

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 dates stored like this:

```
"04.12.2019, 09:35" // Today
"05.12.2019, 12:50" // Some different date
```

And i want to compare them (wether the date has already passed or still will come).

My thought about this was converting them to a Date and then comparing the dates but the online solutions to converting these strings into a date all use moment.js

Is there a way to convert these strings to a date without using moment.js or comparing them without even converting them to a date at all?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `Date` i guess :

```
let dateString = '04.12.2019, 09:35'.replace(/\./g,' ').replace(',', '');
let dateString2 = '05.12.2019, 12:50'.replace(/\./g,' ').replace(',', '');
let newDate = new Date(dateString);
let newDate2 = new Date(dateString2);
//Your comparison between newDate and newDate2 here
```

Comment: When i do this: let A = new Date("04.12.2019, 09:35"); console.log(A); I just get the log: "Invalid Date"

Comment: @niehoelzz you need to replace dots with spaces. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @niehoelzz this should work now. Ah you already solved it :)

Comment: Now i got another problem, since im in germany, we write our dates like this: DD MM JJJJ but Date takes the args like the follwing: MM DD JJJJ. Is there a way to set properties to the "new Date()"?

Comment: @niehoelzz Not that i know, you can invert month and day by string manipulation (using `dateString.split('  ')`)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
let A = new Date("04.12.2019, 09:35");
let B = new Date("05.12.2019, 12:50");

if (A === B) { // Do Stuffs }
```

Comment: When i do this: let A = new Date("04.12.2019, 09:35"); console.log(A); I just get the log: "Invalid Date"

Comment: Which Javascript version you are running in?

Comment: Typescript version 3.5.3

Comment: It should work, I tested in online compiler also. Try to get the debugging point in this line and check the data of date.

Answer (score 0):

[JavaScript Date instance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```js
let date1 = new Date("04.12.2019, 09:35");
let date2 =  new Date("05.12.2019, 12:50");

let result = date1 < date2 ? 'still will come' : 'already passed'; 
console.log(result);
```

Comment: But when i log the date it says "Invalid Date"

Comment: seems its working fine